# Delete a text file from a path using "System.IO" in visual basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, system.io.fileinfo

I have this code:

```
Dim WriterDay1 As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\IOSEagle\Desktop\My Projects\Microsoft Visual Basic 2010\Form\Programes\MyAlarm\MyAlarm\RepeatDays\Monday.txt")
WriterDay1.Write(MondayCheckBox.Text)
WriterDay1.Close()
```

How can I delete this text file From this path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this to get the path:

```
Dim fullPath as String = ((FileStream)(WriterDay1.BaseStream)).Name
```

And then delete the file after it is closed with this:

```
File.Delete(fullPath)
```

Comment: Note: File.Delete is part of System.IO